# Safari can't open any websites after using Jupyter notebook

Tags: safari, jupyter

**iMac Ventura 13.4, with Safari Ver. 16.5 (18615.2.9.11.4)**

I had downloaded Jupyter notebook. I updated Python, and pip, using **Terminal** (Much trial and error! An impressive, but intimidating, beast).

Eventually got Jupyter notebook working. It uses ‘localhost’? (my computer as a server? Not sure what this means)

After a couple of days of trying Jupyter notebook, I logged out of all (I think) the Safari tabs, then tried to open other websites.

Safari can't open any sites. (It worked perfectly before.)

The app opens, but when I click in the search box, my ‘Favourites’ icons show, but are grayed out. (My Reading List icons are also grayed out.)
When I type something in the search box and press enter, the coloured ‘progress line’, under the search box, just moves along a little, then stops/hangs.

Then I get this message:

*“  Safari can’t open the page [ . . . ] because Safari can’t establish a secure connection to the server  [ . . . ]  “*

Then a macOS update ( Ventura 13.4 ) became available, which I allowed, thinking it might help the situation.
No change to Safari after the update, but Google Chrome browser works. I haven’t opened Jupyter notebook in Chrome, in case that gets messed up too.

**What I've tried:**

- I’ve removed all Safari website data (Safari/Privacy/Manage Website Data).
- Deleted all Safari history.
- Have done a Safari ’force quit’.
- There is no ‘Reset Safari’ option.
- I have the Safari ‘Develop’ tab showing, and have done ‘Empty Caches’ in there.
- My time settings look ok.
- All Ethernet Proxies are switched off. One Proxies ‘box’ says “Bypass proxy settings for these hosts and domains: *.local,169.254/16” (No idea what that means).
- DNS Servers are set to 8.8.8.8 then 8.8.4.4.
- Under TCP/IP I did ‘Renew DHCP Lease’.
- I did ’Forget’ my network, then reconnected.
- The fact that Chrome works suggests my network settings are all ok, right?
- Booting into Safe Mode doesn’t help; neither does opening Safari using Shift/Option/Command.
- I don’t have a ‘normal, personal’ router - I’m in a Village, and use what we’re given. I don’t know how to restart the router, so just switched the house mains power off, then on again.
- I can’t find anything obvious on the Jupyter forum, or Stack Overflow, or Ask Different.
- I did try several suggestions from ChatGPT.
- I don't have any extensions or plugins.

Maybe Safari isn’t broken - maybe it just can’t find its usual server? Does this make sense? If so, how do I achieve this?

All the above hasn’t helped. I don’t need Jupyter to work, anywhere  - it’s too complex for me.
Chrome’s still working, and I could live with that, but would prefer Safari to be fixed, if possible.

Comment: "Eventually got Jupyter notebook working. It uses ‘localhost’? (my computer as a 
server? Not sure what this means)" <- Yes. Your understanding is correct. It does run a small web server on your machine.

Comment: "All Ethernet Proxies are switched off. One Proxies ‘box’ says “Bypass proxy settings for these hosts and domains: *.local,169.254/16” (No idea what that means)." <- Where and how did you change this? Are you on Wi-Fi or Ethernet when you tested? Did you test on a different network setup (i.e., if it did not work on Ethernet, try Wi-Fi, vice verse.)

Comment: "I don’t have a ‘normal, personal’ router - I’m in a Village, and use what we’re given. I don’t know how to restart the router, so just switched the house mains power off, then on again." <- If you can find the router device, then you can unplug and replug it, which is better.

Comment: "The fact that Chrome works suggests my network settings are all ok, right?" <- Not necessarily. Chrome might have overridden certain settings like proxy, so we still need to make sure your proxy settings are correct. Chrome does use macOS system keychain's certificates so this part should be likely fine.

Comment: One thing you can try it to ping 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, and ping some random domain like google.com (use terminal) to see if you get any meaningful response.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I installed “Safe Surfer” on my Samsung tablet ages ago, and yesterday just happened to see “Connected to Safe Surfer **VPN**” under the tablet’s Notifications. I had thought it was just an app on the tablet. I had no idea it’s a network thing. And it’s never been a problem until Jupyter/localhost.

Thanks to some probing questions from charlesz, I discovered this filter on my Mac: System Settings/Network/Filters
“  *Safe Surfer, DNS Settings, Enabled*  “ (There’s also a filter enabled for my ESET AntiVirus)

Disabling Safe Surfer solved my problem. Safari now works. Some Favourites icons are still greyed out, but they do open the sites. Some icons get colour back as I watch. I can live with this.

I’ll report this issue to Safe Surfer…

It’s been an education.